# django template form not saving data

Tags: python, django

I have a template form and trying to save some data. Upon clicking on the submit button the page just refreshes and nothing gets saved to the database. I don't get any errors on anything.

## template

```
<form action="" method="post" id="salesform">
         {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="clinic" class="form-control" id="clinic_name" placeholder="Clinic">
        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <button id="sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

## forms.py

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required= True,widget=forms.TextInput())
    clinic_name = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required= True,widget=forms.TextInput())
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=8, required= True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'number'}))
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required= False, widget=forms.TextInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ("clinic_name","phone")
```

## views.py

```
def add_doc_info(request):
    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Doctors",
    'meta_desc' : "Sign up "})

    if request.method == "POST":
        SalesForm = LeadForm(request.POST)

        if SalesForm.is_valid():
            name = SalesForm.cleaned_data['name']
            clinic_name = SalesForm.cleaned_data['clinic_name']
            phone = SalesForm.cleaned_data['phone']
            email = SalesForm.cleaned_data['email']

            #Saving to database
            lead = Lead(name=name, clinic_name=clinic_name, phone=phone, email=email)
            lead.save()


    else:
        SalesForm = LeadForm()


    return render(request,  'm1/add_doc_info.html', d, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## models.py

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(blank = True)
    submitted_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.clinic_name, self.phone)
```

Comment: Did you try debugging by putting some print statements?

Comment: Add debug/print statements and check the flow in the view. Beside that, consider using class views if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly the form is not valid, but you're not using it in your template so there is no way for it to display errors, or redisplay itself with partially-filled fields.

The Django documentation is fairly explicit on this, so I don't know why you have done something different. Pass the form into your context:

```
d['form'] = SalesForm
return render(request, 'm1/add_doc_info.html', d)
```

and use it in the template:

```
{{ form.errors }}
<form action="" method="post" id="salesform">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.name }}
    {{ form.clinic_name }} 
    {{ form.phone }}
    {{ form.email }}
    <button id="sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

(Note also you've unnecessarily defined all the fields explicitly in the form, but also stated you are only using two of them in the meta class; also your is_valid block is mostly unnecessary as you can just call `form.save()` directly. Again, all this is shown fully in the documentation.)